# Load any Image into TImage from TStream

Tags: delphi, stream, timage

I want to make a class to view images in any format. image is stored in blob field.

I create:

```
 const
   ImageType:array [0..6] of TGraphicClass=(TJpegimage, TBitmap, TWICImage,
                                            TGIFImage, TPNGImage, TMetafile,TIcon);

procedure tImageView.LoadFromStream(AStrm: TStream);
var
  Ext: string;
  NewGraphic: TGraphic;
  GraphicClass: TGraphicClass;

  i:integer;
  IsLoaded:boolean;
begin
   IsLoaded:=false;
   for i:=0 to Length(ImageType)-1 do begin
      try
         GraphicClass:=ImageType[i];
         NewGraphic := GraphicClass.Create;
         if Astrm.Size<>0 then begin
            NewGraphic.LoadFromStream(Astrm);
            IsLoaded:=true;
            Break;
            end;
      except
         try
            NewGraphic.Free;
         finally

            end;
         end;
      end;
   if Isloaded then begin
      fImg.Picture.Assign(NewGraphic);
      NewGraphic.Free;
      end
   else begin
      raise EInvalidGraphic.Create('Unknow format image!!!!!!!');
      end;
   end;
```

If first type of image in "ImageType" not correct, then and correct type next index run exception. Why? I must call some init procedure?

Comment: You need to set `Astrm.Position := 0;` each time in the loop after `NewGraphic := GraphicClass.Create`. BTW, I would not use this method. better solution is to check stream header signature.

Comment: You need to set the stream position back to the beginning before you call `LoadFromStream`. But this is a somewhat poor way to do this. Better would be to read the signature of the image and decide on the type that way. Much less expensive. And the `try/finally` is a bit bothersome.

Comment: BTW, `TWICImage` is capable to handle all these formats. so you can use it without using the other graphic classes.